# How to get AppleScript to log the display name of user triggering an Adium event

Tags: applescript, adium

In the Adium chat client, each contact includes a number of event hooks via the "Get Info" window for a contact:

- Contact becomes idle
- Contact goes away
- etc.

Each of these events allows you to hook up an AppleScript when the event triggers. When the event triggers, I'd like to log the name of the contact that triggered the event. Thus far, I've tried a number of different variations on this line of AppleScript code:

```
tell application "Adium" to get display name of contact of active chat
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't yield the right result. I've pored over the Adium API docs and I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you give us some more information such as what errors or results you get and anything else you might have tried.

Comment: The syntax above is correct, however, it doesn't give me the name of the person triggering the event.

Comment: So what does it give you? What else have you tried?

Comment: That only gives me the display name of the user in the active chat. I was hoping that would take the event into account, but it does not.